# Filter by boolean value angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, boolean

im trying to make a filter by the status of the user, "Ativo" for online and "Inativo" for offline, but filtering by string is giving me some headache because when i type "ativo" all the offline users still show up because the word "ativo" exists in "inativo". So i wanted to attach a false value to 'inativo' and a true to 'ativo'.

Any tips on how do i do that? I still what the filter to show "Ativo" and "Inativo" as the options in the datalist, but when selected it should send a true or false value to the filter function

This are the html and the function on ts i created

```
<input type="text" list="status" placeholder="Status" (keyup)="updateFilter($event)" id="stat">   
    <datalist id="status">
      <option>Ativo</option>
      <option>Inativo</option>
    </datalist>
```

```
updateFilter(event: Event) {
    this.filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;    
    this.dataSource.filter = this.filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(this.dataSource.filter);

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you're having the problem with string `ativo` in `inativo` then you were probably trying with `.includes('ativo')`? You don't need to use that method - you can just check for equality, something like `user.status == 'ativo'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Material provides a way to say how the filter should be applied to the data via the filterPredicate method: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource

Providing an arrow function to your datasource that says values should strictly be equal instead of alike should solve you problem.

```
this.datasource.filterPredicate = (data: YourDataType, filter: string) => {
  return data.status === filter;
};
```

Comment: It worked really well, thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

First, if your filter has strict value, you shouldn't use datalist but `select`. It works the same but doesn't allow the user to type in the input.

Now, there is no reason you encounter this kind of problem. Just checking if `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value === 'ativo'` should be enough.

I recommand creating an enum to avoid magic string in your code, so instead of `'ativo'` you will have `UserStatus.ativo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that :

```
var myString = 'ativio';
var myString2 = 'inativio';

new RegExp('\bativio\b').test(myString); // true

new RegExp('\bativio\b').test(myString2); // false
```